# System account in win 7

Tags: windows-7

I had problem with denied access to a program.
Tried to edit users to allow access
Then I denied system access now I have no access to most of the programs even internet
Here is the path I took that caused the problem
Right click a program    properties   security highlighted "SYSTEM"  Edit  Deny
At this point "Window security" pop up. I thought if it did not fix my problem I could go back in and select "Allow" to undo.
Well now I am denied access to almost everything
I can't even do a system restore

Comment: If you denied system access you will have to reverse that action before we can even begin to help you.

Comment: why would you deny access to system?

Answer (score 3):

Boot from a Windows 7 Setup or a Windows Repair disk and [use System Restore](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/what-are-system-recovery-options#what-are-system-recovery-options=windows-7) from there.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

OK, Before we can assist too much, we need to knwo which program (filepath) ??

At a guess,now you are unable to set permissions, you will need to take ownership of the file again to reset permissions.

Try right click > properties > Security > Advanced > Owner Tab > edit > Select your username > OK > ok > ok > ok.

Then when it has changed, right click > properties > security and reset file permissions to how you wanted them in the first place.

When doing this, first disable your antivirus as some AV scanners can see this as suspicious and try to quarrantine files.